# Build a University Notification Application

Tags: java, android, xml

Good afternoon,

I am trying to build a notification application that would connect to the internet to disburse information to students. Currently, I am stuck. My system's processor is 2 gigahertz. The RAM is 2 GB and it is a 32-bit operating system.

With the above specification, I cannot run an emulator on the system even though I downloaded one from the tools package. Currently, I am using my phone, an android device with an API level of 19, a 4.4.2 kit kat, to serve as the emulator. I run the codes and try to see the interface on my phone. Try as much as I did though, nothing shows. It keeps telling me that "Unfortunately, UNB has stopped". UNB stands for University Notice Board.

Also, the AndroidManifest xml file is showing red on some activities and The Noticeboard proper codes written in java has a line that has refused to resolve.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="balaji.cnb"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SampleCodez"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".NetConnection"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".CNB_Login"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".User_Login"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".NoticeBoard"></activity>
</application>
```

[UNB.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMNPB.png)

Comment: (This question was flagged for moderation.) Can you be more specific to the problem?  Screenshots, error outputs, logs, etc.  Also be specific with what one problem you're asking for resolution on - don't bundle two together.

Comment: I have added the screen shot of the error log @wally

Comment: I am still waiting for inputs please...